# Angular 6 how many nested <router-outlet></router-outlet> use

Tags: angular, angular6, router-outlet

In my project, I have two   use in nested level, it's working perfectly, but when I use third  show this error in console

```
If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Can I use  on third level of project structure ?

Is it possible this type of structure

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Users',
        component: Users
      },
      {
        path: 'Admin',
        component: Admin,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'SubAdmin',
            Component: SubAdmin,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'SubAdminOne',
                Component: SubAdminOne
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How many `children` user in nested level ?

Comment: You have to import RouterModule in module where you declared component that uses router-outlet

Comment: @yurzui Yes i am import it, it's working fine with two nested children, can this work with third or fourth level.

Answer (score 0):

Check the modules that declare RootComponent, Admin, and SubAdmin. They should also import the RouterModule from Angular in each case. I think the SubAdmin does not, since you said it was working with two nested.

Answer (score 0):

Import RouterModule in app.module.ts
This should resolve the issue. The problem is not with the number of nested levels.
I have created a similar nested structure and it initially gave me the same error , after importing RouterModule, the error was fixed for third and further nested levels. Have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sge9jf